# How do I proceed in this opening as black in BugHouse?

Tags: checkmate, bughouse

I play bughouse pretty often, but I often end up in the following position (as black).

```
[FEN ""]
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bc4 Bc5 4. Bxf7+ Kxf7 5. d3 Nf6 6. Ng5+
```

In normal chess, it's pretty easy to deal with this (retreat the king, play on)

But in Bughouse, my partner usually ends up trading a lot and I get mated in a few moves.

How do I deal with this position? Should I not let it happen with h6? That seems passive to me. Is there a better option with this opening?

Comment: In bughouse, always protect f7 (or f2 for white) at all cost. So you should prevent that bishop from capturing f7. Generally you want to protect g5 too to prevent knight going there.

Comment: What do you suggest to prevent the bishop from attacking f7

Comment: e6 instead of e5 in the first move.